# I have to ask user to input an array, a1, of length n. Then use a function to print every third element in an array

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm very new to C and I can't quite figure out this problem. 
I have to use the following function to copy every third element in input array `a1[]` of length n into output array `a2[]`

```
    void decimate_by3(int a1[], int n, int a2[])
```

In the `main` function:

- Ask user to input length of array, and elements in the array.
- Calculate length of output array and declare output array.
- Call `decimate_by3` function
- Display output array

I also have constraints which are:

- I have to use the defined `void decimate_by3(int a1[], int n, int a2[]) function as is (no modifications)
- I am not allowed to declare any other functions

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong but i've attached my work so far.. any help is appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void decimate_by3 (int a1[], int n, int a2[])

int main (void)
{
    int n, i;
    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a1[n];
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", n);
    {for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a1[i]);}

    int a2[];
    if (n % 3 == 0)
    int a2[n/3];
    decimate_by3 (a1, n, a2);
    printf("Output: ");
    for (i = 0; i <= (n/3); i++)
        {printf(" %d", a2[i]);}
    else 
        int a2[(n/3)+1];
    decimate_by3 (a1, n, a2);
    printf("Output: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {printf(" %d", a2[i]);}



    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
void decimate_by3 (int a1[], int n, int a2[])
{
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)  
            a1[i] = a2[i];
        else 
            delete;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors that you get when you try to compile your code?

Comment: When you get a compile error you should stop and fix that error, before moving to the next line. I don't even know if that's real code or not. The first line, function declaration `void decimate_by3 (int a1[], int n, int a2[]);` should end in `;` -- `if (condition) int a2[n/3];` doesn't make sense. -- `int a2[];` is invalid --- `else delete;` is invalid ....

Comment: Just from fixing the indentations of your code, I saw many lines of code that are strange. Like this one: `{for (i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &a1[i]);}` why do you enclose the `for` loop in a new context?. Also you access in `decimate_by3` beyond the limits of `a2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an error in this line because of a missing semi-colon:

`void decimate_by3 (int a1[], int n, int a2[])`

You also cannot declare an empty array in C. So this will raise an error:

`int a2[];`

This code should achieve what you want to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void decimate_by3 (int a1[], int n, int a2[]);

int main (void){

  int n, i;
  printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int a1[n];

  printf("Enter %d numbers: \n", n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a1[i]);
  }

  int a2[n/3];
  decimate_by3(a1, n, a2);

  for(i = 0; i < n/3; i++){
    printf("%d ", a2[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

void decimate_by3(int a1[], int n, int a2[]){
  int i, j = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if((i+1)%3 == 0){
      a2[j++] = a1[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this definitely makes a lot more sense but i have to use the function indicated in the question :(

Comment: @KinjalChitroda edited it so that you could use the indicated function :)

Comment: thank you! also, i'm not allowed to use extra functions... so how would i incorporate the 'printArray' function into main

Comment: You just have to move the `for loop` in the main, after the `if-else condition` and replace the `length` with `n/3` and `arr[i]` with `a2[i]`.

Comment: @KinjalChitroda: C allows using extra functions. If you have any artificial constraints, mention them in your question to avoid answers such as this one.

Comment: @KinjalChitroda there you go. I updated it again. As usr2564301 mentioned, don't forget to mention any other constraints for your problem so that other users will better understand the constraints that they need to consider for your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, couple tweaks here and there voila..

```
void decimate_by3(int a1[], int n, int a2[]);

int main(void) {
    int n;

    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n <= 0)
        return 0;

    int a1[n];
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a1[i]);

    int a2[n / 3 + 1];
    decimate_by3(a1, n, a2);

    printf("Output: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < n/3+1; j++) 
        printf("%i ", a2[j]);

    return 0;
}

void decimate_by3(int a1[], int n, int a2[]) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            a2[cnt++] = a1[i];
}
```

Comment: The array is zero indexing so I think that the `if condition` in the `decimate_by3` function should be `(i+1)%3` to check if the ith element is a multiple of 3.

Comment: "every third element" that's what he asked for and 0 is the first one. That's pov I guess, since it is not clearly defined here.

Comment: Yup! So if you have an array say, `arr[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, the 3rd element is `3` and it is located at  `index 2` or `arr[2]` while 6th element is located at `arr[5]`. So you could check if the current element is a `3rd element` if the (index + 1)%3 == 0.

Comment: Ohh I get where you're coming from! Let's just have OP clarify it. :)